# Show wait message while application exit

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following code, Some times ArchiveFiles() take more time to complete its execution.

When user clicks exit option more than one time from context menu, Application becomes non responding if ArchiveFiles() takes more time. How can I show a wait message when he clicks the exit option again?

```
private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ArchiveFiles(); 
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Thanks
Bhaskar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

Using `BackgroundWorker`, you will be able to execute time consuming tasks such as the one you have on another thread so that the UI doesn't freeze. You will be able to report the progress of that task, then report it accomplishement and executing what ever logic you need after its completion.

Handle the [BackgroundWorker.DoWork](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork.aspx) event to start the operation that performs the potentially time-consuming work.

Handle [BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) event to report the progress of an asynchronous operation to the user.

Finaly, handle [BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx) event to implement whatever logic you want to be implemented after the task has been completed.

---

Refer to the following:

[BackgroundWorker Component Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xs8549b.aspx)

[C# BackgroundWorker Tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker)

Answer (score 4):

Create a new `WaitingForm` and put an image control on the form and use the below .gif in that image control which which automatically animate. Then use the code below:

[image]

```
  private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     using (var wait = new WaitingForm())
     {
       wait.Show();
       ArchiveFiles(); 
       Application.Exit();
     }
  }
```

This may not be the best solution but it is the quickest. If you want the form to be a dialog, use `wait.ShowDialog();` instead and carry `ArchiveFiles(); Application.Exit();`
 functions inside it (if that is a probability).

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to run `ArchiveFiles` asynchronously, by either using a `thread` or task, or making some `delegate` and using its `BeginInvoke` method.

You should use then some synchronization object like `ManualResetEvent` so the main thread don't continue executing, calling `Application.Exit()`. Or you could use some event to know when the operation finishes and then call `Application.Exit()` (or call it inside `ArchiveFiles`), but I find that to be worse.

Comment: There are several ways of doing this, although if it is something utterly simple, Teoman's solution may be faster to accomplish. When I replied I thought of something more complex, like showing progress and/or several types of assets.